# Grails db-reverse-engineer fails

Tags: mysql, database, spring, hibernate, grails

I am trying to reverse engineer a database schema and I'm getting the following error:

```
    Command execution error: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Lorg/hibernate/service/ServiceRegistry;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Settings;
    > Building 85% > :dbReverseEngineer :dbReverseEngineer  FAILED
    > Building 85%
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':dbReverseEngineer'.
     Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Grails version:

```
| Grails Version: 3.2.6
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_141
```

Gradle version:

```
Gradle 3.4.1
```

I followed [these the instructions](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-db-reverse-engineer/grails3v4/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin was last released with Grails 3.0.x.  That used gorm 4, I'm pretty sure.  (The docs for Grails 3.1 advertise "What's New" to include gorm 5, and Grails 3.2 advertises gorm 6).  Maybe Burt will chime in, but as far as I can tell, this plugin isn't going to work well in Grails 3.2.x without being re-released.

You could try running it in 3.0.11, just to reverse engineer your classes, and then move those into your real project, as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, ended up doing just that.